# Pass key prop into React component from map

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, createelement

G'Day.  Having a bit of trouble getting the correct was yo pass this key prop into the component creattion.  Here is the code:

```
//--------
render() {

    const that = this;                                                  // Javascript scope voodoo
    const CS = that.parse(this.props.form);                             // CS, or CODE STACK, is the result of a parser that
                                                                        // acts on a JSON description of the form.
                                                                        // It is not QUITE true as CS is a stack of objects
                                                                        // that contain data one WOULD push onto the STACK
                                                                        // SEGMENT in a proper compiler.
    //console.log(CS);

    return(
            <div>
                <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>                              
                {CS.map(function(op, CI) {                              // traverse the CODE SEGMENT and use the CODE INDEX
                    console.log(op);                                    // see what we re mapping to
                    switch (op.component) {                             // what type of operation is this
                        case 'Accordion': {                             // Accordion in a FORM, OK
                            let children = that.pages(op);              // build the children
                            console.log("About to create accordion");   // debugging
                            console.log("with children");               // debugging
                            console.log(children);                      // debugging
                            console.log(op.props);
                            React.createElement(Accordion,              // construct the parent with ALL nested CHILDREN after
                                                {key: CI},              // doing a TDSR evaluation of the OPERAND
                                                children);              // N ACCORDION pages, N2 input fields
                            break;

                        }
                        case 'Workflow': {
                            let children = that.pages(op);              // build the children
                            React.createElement(Workflow,               // and create the complex sheet element
                                                {classname: workflow},
                                                children);              // N SLIDING pages, N2 input fields
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'Simple': {
                            let children = that.pages(op);              // build the children
                            React.createElement(Simple,
                                                {classname: simple},
                                                children);              // One page, N input fields
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                })}
            </div>
    );
}
```

I get a warning from the console that the key is missing and none of my pages are rendered.

Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed a key `prop` to the Accordion component that you have created but not to any other element. You need to pass that to `Workflow` and `Simple` component as well

```
React.createElement(Accordion,           
                 {key: CI},             
                 children);

React.createElement(Workflow,           
                 {classname: Workflow, key: CI},             
                 children);

React.createElement(Simple,           
                 {classname: simple, key: CI},             
                 children);
```